# Como hacer un return redirect()->back() a una ruta post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una ruta post que carga un formulario, y cuando se envía ese formulario, realizo una validación y si esta no se cumple deseo retornar al usuario de nuevo a ese formulario, pero laravel no me lo permite por que este formulario se llama por una ruta post. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer este redirect()->back() pero a una ruta post?

Estas seria el código ejemplo

**Rutas**

```
Route::post('carga-formulario',['uses'=>'miControladorController@cargaFormulario','as'=>'cargaformulario']);
Route::post('recibe-formulario',['uses'=>'miControladorController@recibeFormulario','as'=>'recibeformulario']);
```

**Controlador**

```
public function recibeFormulario(Request $request){
 /**valida y si falla retorna al formulario*/
  if($request->dato){
     return redirect()->back();
 }
/**Continua*/
}
```

Comment: dos rutas post?¿¿? creo que no comprendes el manejo de `GET` y `POST`, pero te aseguro que return redirect()->route('cargaformulario'); tiene que funcionar

Comment: para cargar el formulario, salvo que no comprenda bien tu situación la petición no debería ser POST si no GET

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, les aseguro que comprendo bien el manejo de de GET y POST, solo que para este caso particular necesito saltar entre una serie de formularios donde requiero llamarlos por una petición post, ya que no puedo permitir que el usuario acceda a ellos por petición get, y se mantenga siempre el orden de llamado de los formularios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

creo que para este caso en particular deberías pensar en otras opciones para que los usuarios no puedan acceder a estos formularios sin completar el anterior como un middleware, cookies o cargarlos con javascript.

> ### Middleware o filtros Los componentes llamados Middleware son un mecanismo proporcionado por Laravel para filtrar las peticiones HTTP
>
> que se realizan a una aplicación. Un filtro o middleware se define
>   como una clase PHP almacenada en un fichero dentro de la carpeta
>   `app/Http/Middleware`. Cada middleware se encargará de aplicar un tipo
>   concreto de filtro y de decidir que realizar con la petición
>   realizada: permitir su ejecución, dar un error o redireccionar a otra
>   página en caso de no permitirla.
>
> Laravel incluye varios filtros por defecto, uno de ellos es el
>   encargado de realizar la autenticación de los usuarios. Este filtro lo
>   podemos aplicar sobre una ruta, un conjunto de rutas o sobre un
>   controlador en concreto. Este middleware se encargará de filtrar las
>   peticiones a dichas rutas: en caso de estar logueado y tener permisos
>   de acceso le permitirá continuar con la petición, y en caso de no
>   estar autenticado lo redireccionará al formulario de login.
>
> Laravel incluye middleware para gestionar la autenticación, el modo
>   mantenimiento, la protección contra CSRF, y algunos mas. Todos estos
>   filtros los podemos encontrar en la carpeta `app/Http/Middleware`, los
>   cuales los podemos modificar o ampliar su funcionalidad. Pero además
>   de estos podemos crear nuestros propios Middleware como veremos a
>   continuación.
>
> #### Definir un nuevo Middleware
>
> Para crear un nuevo Middleware podemos utilizar el comando de Artisan:
>
> ```
> php artisan make:middleware MyMiddleware
> ```
>
> Este comando creará la clase `MyMiddleware` dentro de la carpeta
>   `app/Http/Middleware` con el siguiente contenido por defecto:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Middleware;
>
> use Closure;
>
> class MyMiddleware
> {
>     /**
>      * Handle an incoming request.
>      *
>      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>      * @param  \Closure  $next
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
>     {
>         return $next($request);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> El código generado por Artisan ya viene preparado para que podamos
>   escribir directamente la implementación del filtro a realizar dentro
>   de la función handle. Como podemos ver, esta función solo incluye el
>   valor de retorno con una llamada a `return $next($request);`, que lo
>   que hace es continuar con la petición y ejecutar el método que tiene
>   que procesarla. Como entrada la función handle recibe dos parámetros:
>
> - $request: En la cual nos vienen todos los parámetros de entrada de la peticion.
> - $next: El método o función que tiene que procesar la petición.
>
> Por ejemplo podríamos crear un filtro que redirija al home si el
>   usuario tiene menos de 18 años y en otro caso que le permita acceder a
>   la ruta:
>
> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
> {
>     if ($request->input('age') < 18) {
>         return redirect('home');
>     }
>
>     return $next($request);
> }
> ```
>
> Como hemos dicho antes, podemos hacer tres cosas con una petición: Si
>   todo es correcto permitir que la petición continúe devolviendo:
>
> ```
> return $next($request);
> ```
>
> Realizar una redirección a otra ruta para no permitir el acceso con:
>
> ```
> return redirect('home');
> ```
>
> Lanzar una excepción o llamar al método abort para mostrar una página
>   de error:
>
> ```
> abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
> ```
>
> #### Middleware antes o después de la petición Para hacer que el código de un Middleware se ejecute antes o después de la petición HTTP
>
> simplemente tenemos que poner nuestro código antes o después de la
>   llamada a `$next($request);`. Por ejemplo, el siguiente Middleware
>   realizaría la acción antes de la petición:
>
> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
> {
>     // Código a ejecutar antes de la petición
>
>     return $next($request);
> }
> ```
>
> Mientras que el siguiente Middleware ejecutaría el código después de
>   la petición:
>
> ```
> public function handle($request, Closure $next)
> {
>     $response = $next($request);
>
>     // Código a ejecutar después de la petición
>
>     return $response;
> }
> ```
>
> #### Uso de Middleware De momento hemos visto para que vale y como se define un Middleware, en esta sección veremos como utilizarlos.
>
> Laravel permite la utilización de Middleware de tres formas distintas:
>   global, asociado a rutas o grupos de rutas, o asociado a un
>   controlador o a un método de un controlador. En los tres casos será
>   necesario registrar primero el Middleware en la clase
>   `app/Http/Kernel.php`.
>
> #### Middleware global Para hacer que un Middleware se ejecute con todas las peticiones HTTP realizadas a una aplicación simplemente lo tenemos
>
> que registrar en el array `$middleware` definido en la clase
>   `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> protected $middleware = [
>     \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
>     \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
>     \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
>     \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
>     \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
>     \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
>     \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
> ];
> ```
>
> En este ejemplo hemos registrado la clase MyMiddleware al final del
>   array. Si queremos que nuestro middleware se ejecute antes que otro
>   filtro simplemente tendremos que colocarlo antes en la posición del
>   array. Middleware asociado a rutas En el caso de querer que nuestro
>   middleware se ejecute solo cuando se llame a una ruta o a un grupo de
>   rutas también tendremos que registrarlo en el fichero
>   `app/Http/Kernel.php`, pero en el `array $routeMiddleware`. Al
>   añadirlo a este array además tendremos que asignarle un nombre o
>   clave, que será el que después utilizaremos asociarlo con una ruta. En
>   primer lugar añadimos nuestro filtro al array y le asignamos el nombre
>   "es_mayor_de_edad":
>
> ```
> protected $routeMiddleware = [
>     'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
>     'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
>     'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
>     'es_mayor_de_edad' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
> ];
> ```
>
> Una vez registrado nuestro middleware ya lo podemos utilizar en el
>   fichero de rutas `app/Http/routes.php` mediante la clave o nombre
>   asignado, por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> Route::get('dashboard', ['middleware' => 'es_mayor_de_edad', function () {
>     //...
> }]);
> ```
>
> En el ejemplo anterior hemos asignado el middleware con clave
>   es_mayor_de_edad a la ruta dashboard. Como se puede ver se utiliza un
>   array como segundo parámetro, en el cual indicamos el middleware y la
>   acción. Si la petición supera el filtro entonces se ejecutara la
>   función asociada. Para asociar un filtro con una ruta que utiliza un
>   método de un controlador se realizaría de la misma manera pero
>   indicando la acción mediante la clave "uses":
>
> ```
> Route::get('profile', [
>     'middleware' => 'auth',
>     'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
> ]);
> ```
>
> Si queremos asociar varios middleware con una ruta simplemente tenemos
>   que añadir un array con las claves. Los filtros se ejecutarán en el
>   orden indicado en dicho array:
>
> ```
> Route::get('dashboard', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'es_mayor_de_edad'], function () {
>     //...
> }]);
> ```
>
> Laravel también permite asociar los filtros con las rutas usando el
>   método `middleware()` sobre la definición de la ruta de la forma:
>
> ```
> Route::get('/', function () {
>     // ...
> })->middleware(['first', 'second']);
>
> // O sobre un controlador: 
>
> Route::get('profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->middleware('auth');
> ```
>
> #### Middleware dentro de controladores También es posible indicar el middleware a utilizar desde dentro de un controlador. En este caso los
>
> filtros también tendrán que estar registrador en el array
>   $routeMiddleware del fichero `app/Http/Kernel.php`. Para utilizarlos
>   se recomienda realizar la asignación en el constructor del controlador
>   y asignar los filtros usando su clave mediante el método middleware.
>   Podremos indicar que se filtren todos los métodos, solo algunos, o
>   todos excepto los indicados, por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> class UserController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         // Filtrar todos los métodos
>         $this->middleware('auth');
>
>         // Filtrar solo estos métodos...
>         $this->middleware('log', ['only' => ['fooAction', 'barAction']]);
>
>         // Filtrar todos los métodos excepto...
>         $this->middleware('subscribed', ['except' => ['fooAction', 'barAction']]);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### Revisar los filtros asignados Al crear una aplicación Web es importante asegurarse de que todas las rutas definidas son correctas y
>
> que las partes privadas realmente están protegidas. Para esto Laravel
>   incluye el siguiente método de Artisan:
>
> ```
> php artisan route:list
> ```
>
> Este método muestra una tabla con todas las rutas, métodos y acciones.
>   Ademas para cada ruta indica los filtros asociados, tanto si están
>   definidos desde el fichero de rutas como desde dentro de un
>   controlador. Por lo tanto es muy útil para comprobar que todas las
>   rutas y filtros que hemos definido se hayan creado correctamente.
>
> #### Paso de parámetros Un Middleware también puede recibir parámetros. Por ejemplo, podemos crear un filtro para comprobar si el usuario
>
> logueado tiene un determinado rol indicado por parámetro. Para esto lo
>   primero que tenemos que hacer es añadir un tercer parámetro a la
>   función handle del Middleware:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Middleware;
>
> use Closure;
>
> class RoleMiddleware
> {
>     /**
>      * Run the request filter.
>      *
>      * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>      * @param  \Closure  $next
>      * @param  string  $role
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
>     {
>         if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
>             // No tiene el rol esperado!
>         }
>
>         return $next($request);
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> En el código anterior de ejemplo se ha añadido el tercer parámetro
>   `$role` a la función. Si nuestro filtro necesita recibir más parámetros
>   simplemente tendríamos que añadirlos de la misma forma a esta función.
>   Para pasar un parámetro a un middleware en la definición de una ruta
>   lo tendremos que añadir a continuación del nombre del filtro separado
>   por dos puntos, por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', function ($id) {
>     //
> }]);
> ```
>
> Si tenemos que pasar más de un parámetro al filtro los separaremos por
>   comas, por ejemplo: `role:editor,admin`.

Fuente: [GitBooks - "Laravel 5: Capítulo 2 - Filtros"](https://ajgallego.gitbooks.io/laravel-5/content/capitulo_2_filtros.html).

Comment: si bien este enlace puede ser la respuesta, lo ideal es colocar la explicación en esta respuesta de modo tal que aunque con el tiempo el enlace deje de ser funcional, futuros usuarios puedan igualmente acceder a una respuesta de calidad; revisa por favor [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Deberías poder hacer un redirect a la acción en el controlador, algo así:

```
return redirect()->action(
    'miControladorController@cargaformulario',
    ['algunParametro' => $algunParametro]
);
```

Es un poco raro, por decirlo sutilmente, volver a una ruta post, posiblemente podrías estructurar todo esto de otra manera, pero si por X razón es la única manera para tu caso, creo que esto podría servirte y agregué un ejemplo de parámetro en caso que requieras "recuperar" algo del post inicial, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo he intentado pero me genera igualmente un direccionamiento get

Comment: Lo que se indica en la respuesta es lo correcto, deberias retornar una accion del controlador ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions
Ahora bien, dentro de la logica de una aplicación la carga de formularios sucede en un llamado GET no POST.
mira: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477231/3022312